# How to add a new field to every exiting documents with one click for Flutter app

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing a Flutter app where I fetch cloud firestore using stream builder, and works fine also I implemented an admin app to create more list data. The problem is I currently adding Documents field title, *image, address, description*, etc. but now I want to add more fields like *location_url*. To add that field I have to go firebase console and add documents field manually, and it's very painful because I already create 100 plus documents. If I do not add that *location_url* field to existing documents then the client app shows an error. So, Someone please tell me how to add a new field to every exiting documents with one click.

Comment: Actually there is no direct way to change all the documents. But in your flutter client, you could behave more gracefully by just setting the new field to a default value if it cannot be read from the incoming document, how did you parse your json data in the firebase client ?

Answer (score 3):

I understand what you meant, I have been in the same situation !!

Look, when you add a set of fields to cloud firestore , cloud firestore automatically generate an id and structures the field you have added inside that doc or id. To add another field automatically as you are saying is not possible because you will have to give the document id for firebase to know where to add the field.

Unfortunately, there is no way you can achieve the functionality you want. The only solution is to add the missing field manually.

Or you could use a hardcoded value in your client app to avoid the issue, But I don't think that would help you in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Adding new fields, documents or collections to your data model is quite common when using NoSQL databases. And having to deal with the existing data of the older schema is thus also a common problem.

What you have in these situations is a data model/schema before the changes, and a data model/schema after the changes. And you have to make sure your application deals with the changes, also known as a schema migration.

There are two common approaches:

1. Ensure that your client-side code can deal with the absence of new data.
2. Update the existing data to adhere to the new schema.

Neither of these is uniquely better than the other, and in fact: you'll frequently use a combination of both.

**Updating the existing data to adhere to the new schema** is sometimes called backfilling the data, especially when (as you have here) you're adding more data in the new schema.

I typically write a quick helper function for such a backfill operation, either in my application itself, or in a small Node.js script that I make for the purpose. If I write the code in the application itself, I never ship it out to my users: the code is just there for me to run once or twice, and then I remove it again.

In general/addition it is a good idea to **ensure that your client-side code can deal with the absence of new data**, as with schemaless databases it is more common to encounter data that doesn't adhere to your schema.

In this case for example, you can easily set a default value for the new field in your code when you're first reading it from the document: `var value = document['location_url'] ?? 'default value'`.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a python script cli for adding a new field to all documents of a collection using a single command.

Here is the repo.

https://github.com/shubham-chhimpa/fire-script-cli

Answer (score 0):

The way in which I handle this situation is with the use of converters. Firebase provides you with the ability to convert data to and from firebase itself. See [enter link description here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FirestoreDataConverter) for me information.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your answer. I think I solve the problem. I would update the app with the *location_url* feature and I would add an editable button to edit the missing field through the admin app. About error screen for existing list have no *location_url* field yet I add this code below.

```
final universities = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                    final String name = universities["name"];
                    final String address = universities["address"];
                    final String govtprivat = universities["govtprivat"];
                    final String url = universities["url"];
                    final String location_url = universities["location_url"];
```

for one of field will delete or not available, I add this code.

```
title: Text(name==null? 'Name':name,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                  maxLines: 1,
                                ),
                                subtitle: Text(
                                  address==null? 'Address not available':address,
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                  maxLines: 1,
                                ),
```

I hope I have solve this in good way...